# Proving the existence of identity element in a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let *V* be a vector space and *W* be a nonempty subset of *V*. If the closure property under addition and scaler multiplication holds then, *W* is a subspace too.

But if I go ahead and try to prove all the other properties I get stuck while proving the existence of identity element in *W*. Under normal addition, identity element should be 0, which I am not sure belongs to
*W*.
In the textbook, the following statement is given:
Consider *u* such that *u* belongs to *W*. Since *W* is closed under scaler multiplication, so 0*u is in *W*. Now, 0*u=0. Hence 0 is in *W*. Because 0+u=u. Therefore, *W* contains the same additive identity that *V* has.

So can't we prove that every element of *V* belongs to *W*, the way we did with zero?

Comment: Every element of $W$ belongs to $V$ because $W$ is a subspace. If all the elements of $V$ were in $W$ then $V$ would equal $W$.

Comment: Say $(0,1)$ is in the set but $(1,0)$ isn't.  There is no scalar $\lambda$ such that $\lambda (0,1)=(1,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $0\in W$, since $W$ has some element $w$ and therefore $0\times w\in W$, which means that $0\in W$.

I don't see how do you intend to prove that $V\subset W$ by this argument.